# How can I calculate the phase shift of a square membrane by using thermal displacement and mean phonon number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

How can I calculate the phase shift of a square membrane which is considered as harmonic oscillator by using thermal displacement and mean phonon number?
The displacement operator in QM is
$$\langle x^2 \rangle=\frac{\hbar}{2\omega m}(2n +1)$$

$$n=\frac{k_b T}{\hbar\omega}$$

where
$m$ is the mass of the membrane,
$\omega$ is the eigenfrequency of the membrane,
$k_b$ is Boltzmann constant, $T$ is temperature in Kelvin, $\hbar$ is Planck constant$/2\pi$
and $n$ is the mean phonon number.

Comment: What do you means by "phase shift" in this context?

Comment: The membrane oscillates as the laser pass through it , I want to find the phase translation of phonon

Comment: You did not mention any laser in your question.  Why don't  you spell out  exactly what the system is, and what exctly what  you want to compute. We are not mind readers.